# If $g_i$ are LI over $L\subset K$ and $f_j$ are LI over $L$, how can $g_i,f_i$ be LI over $K$?

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm reading Shilov's Linear Algebra. Here:

> [image: -]

Specifically here:

> [image]

I'm extremely confused: If the vectors $g_k$ form a basis of $L\subset K$, how is it possible that we can still pick vectors $f_l$ in $L$ and the set of all these vectors is LI in $K$?

For example, if we take $\Bbb{R}^4$ we split it into the subspaces generates by $(1,0,0,0),(0,1,0,0)$ and $(0,0,1,0), (0,0,0,1)$ and we take $g_1=(1,0,0,0),g_2=(0,1,0,0)$ and $f_1=(1,1,0,0)$ how can these be LI over $\Bbb{R}^4$?

Comment: The $g_k$ are independent **over** $L$ and the $f_k$ are independent **in** $L$.

Comment: I thought that would be the catch but what is the difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $f_k$ are linearly independent vectors lying in $L$.  That means that no nontrivial linear combination of them is $0$.

The $g_k$ are linearly independent **over** $L.$  That means that no nontrivial linear combination of the $g_k$ lies in $L,$ according to definition $2.44$.  In your example, $f_1=(1,1,0,0)=g_1+g_2\in<g_1, g_2>=L$  Thus, $\{f_1\}$ is not linearly independent over $L$.

This is closely related to the the quotient space $K/L$.  Same idea as quotient groups.

Comment: But then, if something is LI over L, it is either zero or some linear combination not in L, isn't it? Because if we have a vector not in L, it can be in L if we set all the coefficients equal to zero.

Comment: @BillyRubina I don't understand what you are asking.  If $v\in L$, $u\notin L$ then $w=v+u\notin L$ and $w-u\in L$ so $\{u,w\}$ is not linearly independent over $L$.  I don't know if this addresses your concern or not.

Comment: Yes. I guess I worded it poorly but I guess I understood it.